# Using Ansible to run playbook from local computer for targeting environment-specific URLs

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

The problem I'm trying to solve with Ansible is to configure several Keycloak servers in different environments using the `community.general.keycloak_role` module.

My basic playbook looks like this and it already does what it is supposed to do. At least when running it locally against `localhost`:

```yaml
- name: Configure Keycloak
  hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: auth_password
      prompt: Please enter Keycloak admin password
  module_defaults:
    community.general.keycloak_role:
      auth_keycloak_url: "{{ auth_keycloak_url }}"
      auth_realm: "{{ auth_realm }}"
      auth_username: "{{ auth_username }}"
      auth_password: "{{ auth_password }}"
      auth_client_id: "{{ auth_client_id }}"
      realm: "{{ realm }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Configure client roles
      community.general.keycloak_role:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        client_id: my-test-client
        state: present
      loop:
        - role_01
        - role_02
        - role_03
```

Now, I'd like to run this playbook for different environments, e.g. `dev`, `staging`, `production` with different URLs and credentials.

My first attempt was to create one inventory file per environment, each containing the hostname.

**inventories/dev**

```
keycloak-dev-server
```

**inventories/staging**

```
keycloak-staging-server
```

But this does not work because Ansible tries to actually connect to these machines, whereas I just want to run the playbook from my local computer targeting the environment. That's why my inventory files now only contain `localhost ansible_connection=local` as hostname and I configure the `auth_keycloak_url` specifically for each environment.

While it works, it "feels" as if this apporach is not correct in the sense that all inventory files only contain a local connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you need a separate set of variables for each environment. If you structure your project like this:

```
.
├── inventories
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   └── all.yaml
│   │   └── hosts.yaml
│   └── staging
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── all.yaml
│       └── hosts.yaml
└── playbook.yaml
```

Then you can put the dev-specific environment variables in `inventories/dev/group_vars/all.yaml` and the staging-specific environment variables in `inventories/staging/group_vars/all.yaml`.

Now you can run either:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i inventories/dev
```

Or:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i inventories/staging
```

And get the appropriate configuration.

---

You can find a runnable example [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-76694696-ansible-environments).